# Simplify list of lists into a single list

Tags: r, list

I have a large dataset that is stored as a list of lists:

```
> str(list1)
List of 100
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:2500, 1:18, 1:14] 0.467 0.556 0.422 0.556 0.511 ...
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:2500, 1:18, 1:14] 0.622 0.644 0.378 0.556 0.667 ...
 $ :List of 1
```

It is stored in a list containing 100 lists of 1.

I would like to simplify this into a single list of the following structure:

```
> str(list2)
List of 100
 $ : num [1:2, 1:4, 1:3] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ : num [1:2, 1:4, 1:3] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ : num [1:2, 1:4, 1:3] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Please ignore the differences in dimensions and values..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the unusual syntax of the exctractor function `[[ ]]`, is in fact a function like any other and can therefore be supplied to `lapply`. By doing this

```
list2 <- lapply(list1, "[[", 1)
```

you are essentially automating this

```
list2 <- list(list1[[1]][[1]],
              list1[[2]][[1]],
              list1[[3]][[1]],
              ... )
```

Alternatively, and perhaps more easy to read is to flatten each element individually, producing the exact same result.

```
list2 <- lapply(list1, unlist)
```

#### Benchmarking

It appears that @akrun's solution is the fastest by far, but unless speed is an issue I suggest you go for the easiest to read. They might also produce different results depending on the data.

```
library(microbenchmark)
list1 <- replicate(100, list(1:100), simplify=FALSE)
microbenchmark(lapply(list1, "[[", 1),
               lapply(list1, unlist),
               unlist(list1, recursive=FALSE))

Unit: microseconds
                             expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq
           lapply(list1, "[[", 1)  32.432  39.2845  43.41272  42.5970  47.1985
            lapply(list1, unlist) 109.011 135.5720 148.27474 153.3045 157.9720
 unlist(list1, recursive = FALSE)   2.733   3.0585   3.94177   3.2430   4.1255
     max neval cld
  73.024   100  b 
 202.294   100   c
  21.860   100 a
```

Answer (score 7):

You could try

```
unlist(list1, recursive=FALSE)
```

#### data

```
list1 <- list(list(structure(1:24, .Dim = c(2L, 4L, 3L))),
 list(structure(1:24, .Dim = c(2L, 
 4L, 3L))), list(structure(1:24, .Dim = c(2L, 4L, 3L))))
```